# pandas concat/update 3 dfs

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 different dfs, all with different columns but 1, ID.
I do not really care about the different data, all I want in the end is a DF containing the IDs and three more columns, each column containing a 1 if the ID is present in the DF or a 0 (or nothing) if the ID is not present.

An example:

DF1

```
index    irrelevant columns
A
B
C
```

DF2

```
index     irrelevant columns2
A
B
F
```

DF3

```
index    irrelevant columns3
A
F
G
```

Final DF

```
index    DF1    DF2    DF3
A         1      1      0
B         1      1      0
C         1      0      0
F         0      1      1
G         0      0      1
```

So far what I am doing (which is extremely bad memory-wise) is (considering index = ID)

```
df1['df1'] = 1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1['df1']) # There has to be a way around this that does not require to create a new DF
df2['df2'] = 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2['df2'])
df3['df3'] = 1
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3['df3'])
data = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], sort=False, axis=1)
```

I am sure there has to be a better way that does not require me to create a new df only with the column, but all that I have tried writes all of the columns of the dfs, and I don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `DataFrame` contructor and [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), then check non missing values by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and cast mask to integers:

```
dfs = {'DF1': DF1, 'DF2': DF2, 'DF3': DF3}

comp = {k: v.index.to_series() for k, v in dfs.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(comp).notna().astype(int)
```

Another solution with `Series` by contructor:

```
comp = {k: pd.Series(1, index=v.index) for k, v in dfs.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(comp).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
   DF1  DF2  DF3
A    1    1    1
B    1    1    0
C    1    0    0
F    0    1    1
G    0    0    1
```

Another solution with [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
dfs = {'DF1': DF1, 'DF2': DF2, 'DF3': DF3}

L = [v.index for k, v in dfs.items()]
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(L),index=list(dfs.keys())).T
print (df)

   DF1  DF2  DF3
0    1    1    1
1    1    1    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    1
4    0    0    1
```